# Console app runs diffrently than in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, java.util.scanner

I made a small card based game in Netbeans. I went to build and test it in the console and it prints eveything twice before the user get to input there move. It does not do it in Netbeans. I am using `scanner.netLine()` to get my input from the console. Here is the code that causes the problem.

```
while(!turnFinished){
     System.out.println(player);//Display the rack
     System.out.println("Here is the discard pile card " + discard.peek());//Display the top card in the discard pile
     System.out.println("If you want the discard pile card press y or press n to pick up a new card from the draw pile.";
     String pickup = scanner.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase();
        
     switch(pickup){
          case "y","yes" ->  {
                   player.drawCardFromDiscard(discard, player, drawPile);//If player decided to pick up from the discard pile 
                   turnFinished = true;
                   }
          case "n","no" ->  {
                   player.drawCardFromDeck(drawPile, discard, player, false);//If player decided to pick up from the draw pile
                   turnFinished = true;
                   }
```

screenshot of netbeans [Netbeans output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiJLE.png)
and [Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6nRQ.png) cmd

[image]

[image]

I tried changing to `scanner.next()` instead of `scanner.nextLine()` but that didn't fix it either. I just want it to display the rack of cards once and wait for the users input like it does in Netbeans.

Comment: Not enough code there. You really need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @g00se While trying to create an example, I got it to work properly in the console by adding a `scanner.nextLine()` before the while loop. Thanks